# Can't build my react in ubuntu without sudo

Tags: server, sudo, nodejs

I have a react project and want to get a build. When I run

> yarn

to install packages, it works fine and installs all packages. after I run

> yarn build

, I get so many nonsense typescript errors like can't find react router type. Why is that? btw if I run

> sudo yarn build

it works fine.